# Undefined method error with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I have a Shop model and a User model. Logic is that users can have one shop and shops can have one users associated with them, so I am using the `has_one: shop` association.

But while creating a new shop for a new user am getting this error

> undefined method 'shops' for #<\User:0x007f6f30659068> Did you mean? shop shop=

I don't understand what's gone wrong. I am sure I must have done something stupid, here's my code:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def new
    @shop = current_user.shop.build
  end

  def create
    @shop = current_user.shops.build(shop_params)
    @shop.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shop.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shop, notice: 'Shop was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shop }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private    
    def shop_params
      params.require(:shop).permit(:name, :description, :imageshop, :location, :web, :email, :phone, :business_type, :category)
    end
end

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :imageshop, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :shop
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
@shop = current_user.shops.build(post_params)
```

to

```
@shop = current_user.build_shop(post_params)
```

This is because you have specified that a User can have one Shop.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer but now am getting this error on the def new `undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Try changing that `current_user.shop.build` to `current_user.build_shop` (from `def new`). More info here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one

Comment: Thanks @Alex it works with a slight change am editing your answer for other people .